# Keeping record from duplicating itself

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have an POS (point of sales) database where we store articles, barcodes (eannos) and orderlines (and much more, but only using these now)

I need to get a list of what articles, and what barcodes have been sold, and i'm nearly there. The only issue I can't seem to get right is articles who have more than one barcode on it (somtimes we add multiple barcodes to the article if the product have different colours, but we want to stick to only one articlenumer)

So my SQL query is:

```
select  Description, eanno, eannoid,  sum(count) from PurchaseOrderLines  
join eannos on PurchaseOrderLines.SizeColorID=EanNos.SizeColorID
where PurchaseOrderLines.articleid in (select articleid from articles where articleno in ('60321129','60314516'))
group by  Description, eanno, eannoid
```

The result is:

```
Description                                 Eanno           Eannoid Sold
Top l/s AOP Baby Dark Sapphire 74           7325850944711   141588  2.00
Top l/s AOP Baby Dark Sapphire 80           7325850944735   141589  2.00
Top l/s AOP Baby Dark Sapphire 86           7325850944759   141590  4.00
Top l/s AOP Baby Dark Sapphire 92           7325850944773   141591  4.00
Bow Tie Solid Preschool Ski Patrol One size 7325851134869   141819  30.00
Bow Tie Solid Preschool Ski Patrol One size 7325851176012   142937  30.00
```

The last line in the result is a duplicate, there has only been sold 30 of "Bow Tie Solid Preschool Ski Patrol One size" but I'm getting duplicate lines because it shows me each barcorde of that same article, and sums the count from orderlines.

How can I make sure only one record shows?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL, some sample data as DML, and desired results.

Comment: I'll try and do that, just need to google what you're asking :)

Comment: `DDL` - Data Definition Language -> create statements of the relevant tables. `DML` - Data Manipulation Language -> Insert statements for sample data.